# Difference between newObject[]{...parameters..} and PreparedStatementSetter Interface implementation in Spring JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-jdbc

What is the difference between passing parameters to SQL statements using the new Object[]{**parameters**} and using the PreparedStatementSetter Interface?

Both provide values to the placeholders in our sql query statement so why should we actually go and provide such long implementation of PreparedStatementSetter Interface when we can just use new Object[] to pass the parameters??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is **convenience**.

`query(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes, ...)` and `query(String sql, Object[] args, ...)` are both *convenience* methods, that internally calls `query(String sql, PreparedStatementSetter pss, ...)`.

Same as `query(..., RowCallbackHandler rch)` and `query(..., RowMapper<T> rowMapper)` both are *convenience* methods, that internally calls `query(..., ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)`.

Convenience methods are nice, because they make the common action a lot easier to do. Providing access to the underlying method allow you to do uncommon actions too, if the need arrives.

As a library, where you never know what the caller might need, it is very appropriate to provide the caller with options to choose from.

Most people will never need the `PreparedStatementSetter` or `ResultSetExtractor` versions, so just ignore them, but do remember that they exist, in case you ever have to need.